# Jquery Clone() inner HTML attributes not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, and when the function Add2List() is executed, it appends the template without having the changes made.

Whats wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Add2List(data, index){

        var $list_item = $('#list-template').clone();

        $list_item.find('.box-list').attr("id", "list_"+data.id);
        $list_item.find('a.list_link').attr("href", data.link);
        $list_item.find('.list_photo').attr("src", data.photo);

        $('#listings_list').append($list_item.html());

        console.log($list_item.html());


}
</script>

<script id="list-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
    <div class="box-list">
        <a class="list_link" href="#">
            <img src="" class="list_photo">
        </a>    
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: You never call the function. `$list` will throw a reference error.

Comment: What `console.log($list_item.html());` show in console?

Comment: @Quentin, the function is called. It appends the HTML as original without the attributes changed, both in the console and in the desired container.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, yes it does, but without the changes in the attributes.

Comment: @user1977790 — It isn't called **in the test case you supplied**

Comment: @user1977790 why are you putting html inside script tag. Html is not javascript. Did you mean to render it as text hence type="text/x-custom-template" ?

Comment: @NKD — The type attribute says it isn't JavaScript too, so what's the problem? Why would `type="text/x-custom-template"` cause it to be **rendered** at all? This is a fairly common hack to provide a template for JS to read later.

Comment: @Quentin yah i notice that. Just clarified. Wonder why it is not just text. Just want to understand what he is doing.

Comment: @Quentin ah got it. Thanks. I have not used that hack before. Learn something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're cloning the `<script>` tag instead of the html inside. Use `$( $('#list-template').html() )` instead ([demo](http://jsbin.com/tewezuyiko/edit?js,output))

```
function Add2List(data, index){  
  var $list_item = $($('#list-template').html());

  $list_item.attr("id", "list_"+data.id);
  $list_item.find('a.list_link').attr("href", data.link);
  $list_item.find('.list_photo').attr("src", data.photo);

  $('#listings_list').append($list_item);
  console.log(data, $list_item.html());    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @GabyakaG.Petrioli, fixed

Comment: You are right, I was cloning the <script> tag. This makes sense and works. The <script> tag here was assumed as text and not as a DOM tree of elements, that's why it was not changing the children, right?
(not sure If I explained myself correctly)

Comment: Yes, a script tag can not contain DOM elements (I was looking for the spec, but can't find it).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with jquery not handling the html correctly because it is inside the script tag (*or it is a DOM issue*).

Doing

```
var $list_item = $('<div>', {
                    html: $('#list-template').html()
                 });
```

instead of cloning it fixes the problem.

---

What it does is to create a `div` element in memory that holds the contents of the template (*and work on that thereafter*).

Comment: This is correct and also works, however, not in my case as I don't want to add it into a new div.
Upvoted, but chosen another answer as it has a working demo, does exactly what I want and was posted earlier. Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Comment: @user1977790 not a problem. Just keep in mind though that since you append the `.html()` it is the same thing. In both cases you append the contents of the element you have in memory. (*in other words the container `div` is not added.*)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter('#list-template')` before `find` will solve the problem since you're trying to `find` the current root element in your `$list_item` variable that is a `.box-list` :

```
function Add2List(data, index){
    var $list_item = $('#list-template').clone();

    $list_item.filter('#list-template').find('.box-list').attr("id", "list_"+data.id);
    $list_item.filter('#list-template').find('a.list_link').attr("href", data.link);
    $list_item.filter('#list-template').find('.list_photo').attr("src", data.photo);

    $('#listings_list').append($list_item.html());

    console.log($list_item.html());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was just a result of the code change for posting. Thanks for helping me finding out. Just edited the source. 
Still, that was not the problem.

Comment: the other elements are not children though.

Comment: Yes @GabyakaG.Petrioli your right, check my update please.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your cloned object is not attached to anything. jQuery's .find runs on an object that exists.

You can do this via a `preg_match` but since you are templating - the best thing to use is [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).